# Programmatically go back to consecutive 3rd previous ViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have seen too much threads on how to go back to previous View controller, that makes sens and are easy also to implement. But in my case there is only one type of complication. Consider the following situation.

- **VC1 --Opens--> VC2:** vc2 is a viewcontroller that is showing a Form. On correct filling the user is taken to another VC. call it vC3
- **VC2 --Opens--> VC3:** vc3 is a view controller that takes swipe card information and if the information provided is correct it takes to VC4
- **VC3 --Opens--> VC4:**.

> VC4 is the viewcontroller that loads up all user contacts and send
>   information/data to that selected contact. SO far it is fine. now
>   there is 2 conditions, if the data that I send is correctly sent then
>   I have to go back to VC1 directly, and if the data is not sent then I
>   have to go back to vc2 directly to take up information again.

so what are the best thing to handle this situation. Please suggest.

**UPDATE:**

> I am using Tab bar controller, in that controller under one of that View , I am opening other VIew controller from this in series. Like from this Opening VC2 that opens VC3 and so on...

**This is how I am showing my ViewController 2**

```
let myVC2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "idMyVC2") as MyVC2 
myVC2.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen 
self.present(myVC2,animated : true)
```

Comment: Are you working with storyboard segues, or do you want to do this via direct UINavigationController `pop...`?

Comment: How are you presenting the `VC2` from `VC1`, `VC3` from `VC2` and so on?

Comment: read updated question now

Comment: So you are presenting 3rd and 4th with the same presentation model?

Comment: yes.............

Comment: Just chain delegates between all of the view controllers that you are presenting and use them to dismiss the specific view controller on top of the one that you want to go back to. If A presents B, B presents C, C presents D, and D presents E, if you go through the delegate and dismiss B (from E), it will automatically dismiss C, D, and E together and take the user back to A.

Comment: can you show me how to use that chain way? I just know that while starting the VC3 from VC2 I can implement Delegate on VC2 for VC3 , and VC2 will listen to delegate call by VC3 , for example ListSentCloseVC2 is called from VC3, and VC3 close it self also , then VC2 will have to launch method call by delegate and then we can close VC2 in that delegated method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug this into a playground and mess around with it:

```
import UIKit

protocol DismissDelegate: AnyObject {
    func dismissVC(_ presenting: Int)
}

class VC1: UIViewController, DismissDelegate {
    func dismissVC(_ presenting: Int) {
        guard presenting == 1 else {
            return
        }
        print("dismiss 2, 3, 4, 5")
    }
}
class VC2: UIViewController, DismissDelegate {
    weak var vc2Delegate: DismissDelegate?
    func dismissVC(_ presenting: Int) {
        guard presenting == 2 else {
            return vc2Delegate!.dismissVC(presenting)
        }
        print("dismiss 3, 4, 5")
    }
}
class VC3: UIViewController, DismissDelegate {
    weak var vc3Delegate: DismissDelegate?
    func dismissVC(_ presenting: Int) {
        guard presenting == 3 else {
            return vc3Delegate!.dismissVC(presenting)
        }
        print("dismiss 4, 5")
    }
}
class VC4: UIViewController, DismissDelegate {
    weak var vc4Delegate: DismissDelegate?
    func dismissVC(_ presenting: Int) {
        guard presenting == 4 else {
            return vc4Delegate!.dismissVC(presenting)
        }
        print("dismiss 5")
    }
}
class VC5: UIViewController {
    weak var vc5Delegate: DismissDelegate?
    func dismissStack(at presenting: Int) {
        vc5Delegate?.dismissVC(presenting)
    }
}

let vc1 = VC1()

let vc2 = VC2()
vc2.vc2Delegate = vc1

let vc3 = VC3()
vc3.vc3Delegate = vc2

let vc4 = VC4()
vc4.vc4Delegate = vc3

let vc5 = VC5()
vc5.vc5Delegate = vc4

vc5.dismissStack(at: 1) // prints: dismiss 2, 3, 4, 5
vc5.dimissStack(at: 2) // prints: dismiss 3, 4, 5
```

The setup is very basic, each view controller is chained through a delegate. Because there is more than one view controller, we created a protocol. That protocol is just a method that takes an integer argument which is the view controller that should perform the dismiss (the presenting view controller). Then when you want to perform a dismiss, call the delegate (doesn't have to be from the 5th view controller), specify the presenting view controller, and the delegate will go down the chain and check if it's the presenting view controller (if it is, it will dismiss everything above it) or not (if it isn't, it will step down one view controller and repeat the process).

`VC5` has a method called `dismissStack(at:)` which lets you put in an integer of the view controller you want to dismiss at. Therefore, if you dismiss at 2, then view controllers 3, 4, 5 will be dismissed. You can, obviously, place this method into the other view controllers as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in various way, one them is like below:-

Hierarchy of view controllers be like :-

NavigationController -> VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3 -> VC4(using push).Now use below code to change your controller

If pop to root use :-

```
for controller in self.navigationController!.viewControllers as Array {
    if controller.isKind(of: VC1) {
        self.navigationController!.popToViewController(controller, animated:    true)
        break
    }
}
```

if for pop go to at VC3 simply pop to root.

I hope it will help you,

Thanks

Comment: I dont have Navigation controller

Comment: @SharartiKAKI as per your mentioned better way to that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way i used

```
for controller in self.navigationController!.viewControllers 
{
    if let vc = controller as? LoginViewController 
    {
        self.navigationController!.popToViewController(vc, animated:    true)
              break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

way that i used most is

```
for controller in self.navigationController.controllers {
      if let desiredVC = controller as? DesiredViewControllerName {
          self.navigationController!.popToViewController(desiredVC, animated: true)
      }
}
```